# Parser Matching any Token in Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a parser that gets fed by a lexer with many different tokens. I want to write a parser that parses any token except one. The boost::spirit documentation offers examples for cases without a lexer:

```
confix("/*", "*/")[*(char_ - "*/")]  // C style comment

confix("//", eol)[*(char_ - eol)]    // C++ style comment
```

In the second examples the `char_` parser parses any input hence the `(char_ - eol)` parses anything but the end of line.

I want to achieve the very same effect but don't know how to create a parser that accepts any ***input token***. Of course I could list all my tokens as options in one parser and use this one as the "any-parser".

However, this is very error prone since I have to remember to add each new token to this parser.

Comment: Interesting question. I think the usage pattern is highly unusual (lexing mostly implies a well-determined formal grammar) but I can see why you'd like this behaviour